# Sequelize generates empty migrations

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Assuming my ES6 JavaScript project with Sequelize, I have three different model files.

My `sequelize.rc` config file is well configured, but when I want to generate the very **first** migration files for my brand new models with `migration:generate`:

```sh
node-user@778125a03bb5:/usr/app$ ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize migration:generate --name init

Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.17.1, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.6.2]

Successfully created migrations folder at "/usr/app/src/database/migrations".
New migration was created at /usr/app/src/database/migrations/20210624144147-init.js .
```

The migration file the command generates is empty (it only has a squeleton):

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    /**
     * Add altering commands here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.createTable('users', { id: Sequelize.INTEGER });
     */
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    /**
     * Add reverting commands here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
     */
  }
};
```

So how can I make it generating consistent migration files according to my models?
Is there any way to automate that, like TypeORM does?

Comment: I'm I'm facing the same issue please anyone knows what is the problem ?